# Load a class with a single object fetch

Tags: php, class

I have some PHP classes which describe a single row in some database tables.
Now I load this class with a sentence like the following:

```
$obj = new Object;
$obj->loadField($id); --> This loads the $id field from the database
```

I'm thinking about changing the behaviour in this way:

```
$obj = new Object($id);
```

Can you advise me the correct implementation or some best practices about this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show the code of `Object`?

Comment: Constructors can only be implemented in one way... your question does not make much sense. Maybe you should expand on what you mean by "correct implementation" and "best practices".

Answer (score 4):

Define the constructor like this:

```
class Object {
    public function __construct($id = 0) {
        if(!empty($id)) {
            $this->loadField($id);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can use both ways to load the object.

Comment: This makes no sense. How will you obtain the id while having no further information? The id or other combination of unique data is required in order to obtain object's data from the database.

Comment: i think `$id` should be `null` not `0`, am i right?

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the default value is `0`, `NULL`, `FALSE` or `''` as they all are `empty`, I just always use the same data type as the expected value (so 0, empty string or empty array). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not quite sure what you mean. The id can be obtained in many ways (URL parameter, value of another object etc.) Anyway in the question `$id` is already present.

Comment: how should the id being obtained having your code? (The question explicitly states that it is about database rows.)

Comment: That wasn't part of the question. He only asked how to pass the id directly to the constructor instead of to the `loadField` method. As I said there are many ways of obtaining the id and it really depends on the use case.

Comment: The ID is always obtained from a search, so I always have an ID.